# Extract longitude and latitude to either one or two cells, from one cell text string in Excel

Tags: excel, replace, extract, converters

[image]

From the picture above, I'm trying to extract the specific longitude and latitude out of the text string named location. I would like to create new rows with just longitude and latitude from the text string. Can someone show me a formula that could do this?

Kindest Regards,
Snow

Answer (score 1):

For longitude:

```
=MID(R3,(FIND("{'longitude': '",R3)+15),(FIND("', ",R3)-(FIND("{'longitude': '",R3)+15)))
```

For latitude:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(R3,(FIND("'latitude': '",R3)+13),100),"'}","")
```